# To string with adding bracket

Tags: java, tostring

Trying to delete the last comma and instead add an end bracket. How to go about this?

My code:

```
    @Override
    public String toString(){
    String str="[";
    for(double d:data) str+=d+", ";
    return str;

}
```

Example data:

```
stat1 data = [  
stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0,  
stat1 data = [70.0, 80.0,  
stat1 data = [90.0, 100.0,  
stat1 data = [100.0, 110.0,  
stat1 data = [
```

Comment: That is what you get for using a for each loop. If you actually do a for loop based on the length it won't be difficult to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's hard to tell, ahead of time, when an element you're looking at in an iterator is the last one.  In cases like this, it often works best to append the comma *before* each element instead of after, except for the first element.  Thus:

```
String str = "[";
boolean first = true;
for (double d : data)  {
    if (!first) {
        str += ", ";
    }
    str += d;
    first = false;
}
str += "]";
```

Another possibility is to use the logic you have now but use `substring` or `replace` or some other method to remove the extra two characters, like

```
str = str.replaceFirst(", $", "]");
```

which uses a regular expression to replace `", "` that appears at the end of the string with a right bracket.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to just print the data in the `toString` method and add the typographical elements like '[' or comma separately accompanied with an `if` statement. 
However if you insist to stick just to the `toString` method, add a `boolean` field to the class and set it to true if something is the last object and inside the `toString` method, check that field and do the right decision.